# set page margins programmatically in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, margin

I m using crystal report for one of my report. I need to set the margins dynamically for the report. The margins are being set by user so I need to apply the margins programmatically.

I am using the below code to set the margins programmatically.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
PageMargins pageMargins = new PageMargins();
pageMargins.leftMargin = 25;
pageMargins.topMargin = 100;
pageMargins.rightMargin = 25;
pageMargins.bottomMargin = 50;
rd.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(pageMargins);
```

and then show preview of print to the user and then user can print. I am using below code for showing preview.

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "Print");
```

Above is not working for me. It doesn't apply margins (The same is working when I set margins statically from **Design -> Page Setup**). It shows the content as if margins are not applied when used dynamically. I have attached the image for how it is being shown as preview.

[image: Preview of report]

Can anybody help me for what can be the problem? Why margins are not being applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. There is only a little change with the code I used earlier. I used the code below.

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
PageMargins margins;
// Get the PageMargins structure and set the 
// margins for the report.
margins = rd.PrintOptions.PageMargins;
margins.bottomMargin = 350;
margins.leftMargin = 600;
margins.rightMargin = 350;
margins.topMargin = 300;
// Apply the page margins.
rd.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(margins);
```

So the above is working fine. We just need to get the report document page margins and set the margins there instead of new initialization of **PageMargins** object.