# Crystal Reports .NET - Setting page margins dynamically by code

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, margins

I have a bunch of reports with margin formulas. The page margins depend on the current page number and the current page orientation. The formulas are the same in every report. I want to set those formulas by code so I won't have to change every margin in every report manually when the corporate design changes.

What I already found was the BeforeFormatPage-Event. The EventArgs contain only the current page number. What I need is the current page orientation for setting the margins correctly. And this is where I'm stuck at the moment.
Is this possible at all and if yes, how can I do this?

Comment: May be this is what you need to look at. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426112/set-page-margins-programmatically-in-crystal-report

Comment: No, because the page margins in this thread are the same for all pages of the report. I have to set them differently for every page and they depend on the page number and the page orientation.